# Can't set type JSON for object in swift

Tags: ios, json, xcode, swift

Hi all i'm using Xcode 7 and swift2 but for some weird reason i'm unable to set an data object of type JSON, i've tried using different types and they seem to come up on the intellisense but for some reason JSON is available when it previously was..

The error i'm getting is

**Use of undeclared type JSON**

This is the format of my data in a blank swift file it's worth note mentioning that using the word JSON doesn't turn green like it normally should.

```
var data: JSON = [

    "stories" : [

        [
            "Article_Link" : "http://www.webdesignernews.com/redirect?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.creativebloq.com%2Fweb-design%2Fweb-designers-take-centre-stage-new-sitcom-91516753",
            "Article_Shares" : "",
            "Article_Time" : "44 min ago",
            "Article_Title" : "Web Designers Take Centre Stage in New Sitcom",
            "icon" : "Web-Designer-Depot",
            "index" : 2,
            "source" : "Web Designer Depot",
            "url" : "http://www.webdesignernews.com/",
        ],
        [
            "Article_Link" : "http://www.webdesignernews.com/redirect?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.webdesignerdepot.com%2F2015%2F09%2Fwhats-new-for-designers-september-2015%2F",
            "Article_Shares" : "203",
            "Article_Time" : "50 min ago",
            "Article_Title" : "What's New for Designers, September 2015",
            "icon" : "Web-Designer-Depot",
            "index" : 3,
            "source" : "Web Designer Depot",
            "url" : "http://www.webdesignernews.com/",
        ],
        [
            "Article_Link" : "http://www.webdesignernews.com/redirect?url=http%3A%2F%2Fblog.atomic.io%2Fnews%2Fadvanced-motion-control-now-in-atomic%2F",
            "Article_Shares" : "68",
            "Article_Time" : "1 hour ago",
            "Article_Title" : "New in Atomic Prototype with Advanced Motion Control + Swipe Gestures",
            "icon" : "Web-Designer-Depot",
            "index" : 4,
            "source" : "Web Designer Depot",
            "url" : "http://www.webdesignernews.com/",
        ]

       ]
    ]
```

Comment: There is no such type as `JSON`. The data is a dictionary. In Swift, you can skip the type and declare it this way: `var data = ...`.

Comment: @Adam ahh okay would it be cool to pass this into a method with type of AnyObject?

Comment: You could add the `SwiftyJSON` class (available on GitHub) which contains a `JSON` type then you can create a `JSON` object with `let json = JSON(arrayLiteral: data)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compiler have all rights to throw that error. There is no data type called `JSON` existing in Swift. You should use dictionary instead.